# mysql sum depending on a part of a cell's content

Tags: mysql, regex, sum

I've this table:

```
id    value     ref
1       0        10000
2       5        11000
3       5        11100
4       2        11101
5       2        11102
6      10        12000
...    ...         ....
```

How can i achieve this:

```
ref    sum(value)
10000   14         <-- 5 + 5 + 2 + 2
11000   9          <-- 5 + 2 + 2
11100   4          <-- 2 + 2
12000   10         <-- and so on
```

I can't decided if this desing is valid, it won't work, or i'm missing something.

I don't have any sql query to show to you guys.

Using regex, maybe? which i'd read about it, but not fully understand.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work for you, after replacing `contentsum` with the real name of your table:

```
select rpad(main.prefix, 5, 0) as ref, sum(contentsum.value) as total
    from (select distinct trim(trailing '0' from ref) as prefix from contentsum) as main
    join contentsum on contentsum.ref like concat(main.prefix, '%')
    group by main.prefix
;
```

However, its totals don't match yours.  Instead, they match what I thought you were adding up when I first read the question.

Basically, the key is to JOIN the table to itself on some function of the `ref` values, grouping by the left-hand side, and summing over the right-hand side.  The subquery condenses identical rows and reduces some code duplication, but isn't strictly necessary if the `ref` values are all unique.